# Grouping multiple values into one factor in one column in RStudio

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a dataset which contains multiples cities and their sales regions in one column, they are repeatedly shown in this column due to they are separated by the next two columns product types and dates. I already converted each region to factor:

```
avocadodata$Region <- factor(avocadodata$Region, levels = c("California","West","Plains","South Central","Great Lakes","Northeast","Midsouth","Southeast"), labels = c("California","West","Plains","South Central","Great Lakes","Northeast","Midsouth","Southeast"))
```

Then use `summary(avocadodata$Region)` to check and find out the cities were `NA's` because I didn't convert them to factors.

[image]

How to convert cities to one single factor which also separated by the next two columns product types and dates? So I don't get `Na's` in `summary(avocadodata$Region)`?

(Please check the dataset, you will have an idea about this case)

```
Region  Date    Type
Albany  2019/1/7    Conventional
Atlanta 2019/1/7    Conventional
Baltimore/Washington    2019/1/7    Conventional
Boise   2019/1/7    Conventional
Boston  2019/1/7    Conventional
Buffalo/Rochester   2019/1/7    Conventional
California  2019/1/7    Conventional
Charlotte   2019/1/7    Conventional
Chicago 2019/1/7    Conventional
Cincinnati/Dayton   2019/1/7    Conventional
Columbus    2019/1/7    Conventional
Dallas/Ft. Worth    2019/1/7    Conventional
Denver  2019/1/7    Conventional
Detroit 2019/1/7    Conventional
Grand Rapids    2019/1/7    Conventional
Great Lakes 2019/1/7    Conventional
Harrisburg/Scranton 2019/1/7    Conventional
Hartford/Springfield    2019/1/7    Conventional
Houston 2019/1/7    Conventional
Indianapolis    2019/1/7    Conventional
Jacksonville    2019/1/7    Conventional
Las Vegas   2019/1/7    Conventional
Los Angeles 2019/1/7    Conventional
Louisville  2019/1/7    Conventional
Miami/Ft. Lauderdale    2019/1/7    Conventional
Midsouth    2019/1/7    Conventional
Nashville   2019/1/7    Conventional
New Orleans/Mobile  2019/1/7    Conventional
New York    2019/1/7    Conventional
Northeast   2019/1/7    Conventional
Northern New England    2019/1/7    Conventional
Orlando 2019/1/7    Conventional
Philadelphia    2019/1/7    Conventional
Phoenix/Tucson  2019/1/7    Conventional
Pittsburgh  2019/1/7    Conventional
Plains  2019/1/7    Conventional
Portland    2019/1/7    Conventional
Raleigh/Greensboro  2019/1/7    Conventional
Richmond/Norfolk    2019/1/7    Conventional
Roanoke 2019/1/7    Conventional
Sacramento  2019/1/7    Conventional
San Diego   2019/1/7    Conventional
San Francisco   2019/1/7    Conventional
Seattle 2019/1/7    Conventional
South Carolina  2019/1/7    Conventional
South Central   2019/1/7    Conventional
Southeast   2019/1/7    Conventional
Spokane 2019/1/7    Conventional
St. Louis   2019/1/7    Conventional
Syracuse    2019/1/7    Conventional
Tampa   2019/1/7    Conventional
West    2019/1/7    Conventional
West Tex/New Mexico 2019/1/7    Conventional
Albany  2019/1/7    Organic
Atlanta 2019/1/7    Organic
Baltimore/Washington    2019/1/7    Organic
Boise   2019/1/7    Organic
Boston  2019/1/7    Organic
Buffalo/Rochester   2019/1/7    Organic
California  2019/1/7    Organic
Charlotte   2019/1/7    Organic
Chicago 2019/1/7    Organic
Cincinnati/Dayton   2019/1/7    Organic
Columbus    2019/1/7    Organic
Dallas/Ft. Worth    2019/1/7    Organic
Denver  2019/1/7    Organic
Detroit 2019/1/7    Organic
Grand Rapids    2019/1/7    Organic
Great Lakes 2019/1/7    Organic
Harrisburg/Scranton 2019/1/7    Organic
Hartford/Springfield    2019/1/7    Organic
Houston 2019/1/7    Organic
Indianapolis    2019/1/7    Organic
Jacksonville    2019/1/7    Organic
Las Vegas   2019/1/7    Organic
Los Angeles 2019/1/7    Organic
Louisville  2019/1/7    Organic
Miami/Ft. Lauderdale    2019/1/7    Organic
Midsouth    2019/1/7    Organic
Nashville   2019/1/7    Organic
New Orleans/Mobile  2019/1/7    Organic
New York    2019/1/7    Organic
Northeast   2019/1/7    Organic
Northern New England    2019/1/7    Organic
Orlando 2019/1/7    Organic
Philadelphia    2019/1/7    Organic
Phoenix/Tucson  2019/1/7    Organic
Pittsburgh  2019/1/7    Organic
Plains  2019/1/7    Organic
Portland    2019/1/7    Organic
Raleigh/Greensboro  2019/1/7    Organic
Richmond/Norfolk    2019/1/7    Organic
Roanoke 2019/1/7    Organic
Sacramento  2019/1/7    Organic
San Diego   2019/1/7    Organic
San Francisco   2019/1/7    Organic
Seattle 2019/1/7    Organic
South Carolina  2019/1/7    Organic
South Central   2019/1/7    Organic
Southeast   2019/1/7    Organic
Spokane 2019/1/7    Organic
St. Louis   2019/1/7    Organic
Syracuse    2019/1/7    Organic
Tampa   2019/1/7    Organic
West    2019/1/7    Organic
West Tex/New Mexico 2019/1/7    Organic
Albany  2019/1/13   Conventional
Atlanta 2019/1/13   Conventional
Baltimore/Washington    2019/1/13   Conventional
Boise   2019/1/13   Conventional
Boston  2019/1/13   Conventional
Buffalo/Rochester   2019/1/13   Conventional
California  2019/1/13   Conventional
Charlotte   2019/1/13   Conventional
Chicago 2019/1/13   Conventional
Cincinnati/Dayton   2019/1/13   Conventional
Columbus    2019/1/13   Conventional
Dallas/Ft. Worth    2019/1/13   Conventional
Denver  2019/1/13   Conventional
Detroit 2019/1/13   Conventional
Grand Rapids    2019/1/13   Conventional
Great Lakes 2019/1/13   Conventional
Harrisburg/Scranton 2019/1/13   Conventional
Hartford/Springfield    2019/1/13   Conventional
Houston 2019/1/13   Conventional
Indianapolis    2019/1/13   Conventional
Jacksonville    2019/1/13   Conventional
Las Vegas   2019/1/13   Conventional
Los Angeles 2019/1/13   Conventional
Louisville  2019/1/13   Conventional
Miami/Ft. Lauderdale    2019/1/13   Conventional
Midsouth    2019/1/13   Conventional
Nashville   2019/1/13   Conventional
New Orleans/Mobile  2019/1/13   Conventional
New York    2019/1/13   Conventional
Northeast   2019/1/13   Conventional
Northern New England    2019/1/13   Conventional
Orlando 2019/1/13   Conventional
Philadelphia    2019/1/13   Conventional
Phoenix/Tucson  2019/1/13   Conventional
Pittsburgh  2019/1/13   Conventional
Plains  2019/1/13   Conventional
Portland    2019/1/13   Conventional
Raleigh/Greensboro  2019/1/13   Conventional
Richmond/Norfolk    2019/1/13   Conventional
Roanoke 2019/1/13   Conventional
Sacramento  2019/1/13   Conventional
San Diego   2019/1/13   Conventional
San Francisco   2019/1/13   Conventional
Seattle 2019/1/13   Conventional
South Carolina  2019/1/13   Conventional
South Central   2019/1/13   Conventional
Southeast   2019/1/13   Conventional
Spokane 2019/1/13   Conventional
St. Louis   2019/1/13   Conventional
Syracuse    2019/1/13   Conventional
Tampa   2019/1/13   Conventional
West    2019/1/13   Conventional
West Tex/New Mexico 2019/1/13   Conventional
Albany  2019/1/13   Organic
Atlanta 2019/1/13   Organic
Baltimore/Washington    2019/1/13   Organic
Boise   2019/1/13   Organic
Boston  2019/1/13   Organic
Buffalo/Rochester   2019/1/13   Organic
California  2019/1/13   Organic
Charlotte   2019/1/13   Organic
Chicago 2019/1/13   Organic
Cincinnati/Dayton   2019/1/13   Organic
Columbus    2019/1/13   Organic
Dallas/Ft. Worth    2019/1/13   Organic
Denver  2019/1/13   Organic
Detroit 2019/1/13   Organic
Grand Rapids    2019/1/13   Organic
Great Lakes 2019/1/13   Organic
Harrisburg/Scranton 2019/1/13   Organic
Hartford/Springfield    2019/1/13   Organic
Houston 2019/1/13   Organic
Indianapolis    2019/1/13   Organic
Jacksonville    2019/1/13   Organic
Las Vegas   2019/1/13   Organic
Los Angeles 2019/1/13   Organic
Louisville  2019/1/13   Organic
Miami/Ft. Lauderdale    2019/1/13   Organic
Midsouth    2019/1/13   Organic
Nashville   2019/1/13   Organic
New Orleans/Mobile  2019/1/13   Organic
New York    2019/1/13   Organic
Northeast   2019/1/13   Organic
Northern New England    2019/1/13   Organic
Orlando 2019/1/13   Organic
Philadelphia    2019/1/13   Organic
Phoenix/Tucson  2019/1/13   Organic
Pittsburgh  2019/1/13   Organic
Plains  2019/1/13   Organic
Portland    2019/1/13   Organic
Raleigh/Greensboro  2019/1/13   Organic
Richmond/Norfolk    2019/1/13   Organic
Roanoke 2019/1/13   Organic
Sacramento  2019/1/13   Organic
San Diego   2019/1/13   Organic
San Francisco   2019/1/13   Organic
Seattle 2019/1/13   Organic
South Carolina  2019/1/13   Organic
South Central   2019/1/13   Organic
Southeast   2019/1/13   Organic
Spokane 2019/1/13   Organic
St. Louis   2019/1/13   Organic
Syracuse    2019/1/13   Organic
Tampa   2019/1/13   Organic
West    2019/1/13   Organic
West Tex/New Mexico 2019/1/13   Organic
Albany  2019/1/20   Conventional
Atlanta 2019/1/20   Conventional
Baltimore/Washington    2019/1/20   Conventional
Boise   2019/1/20   Conventional
Boston  2019/1/20   Conventional
Buffalo/Rochester   2019/1/20   Conventional
California  2019/1/20   Conventional
Charlotte   2019/1/20   Conventional
Chicago 2019/1/20   Conventional
Cincinnati/Dayton   2019/1/20   Conventional
Columbus    2019/1/20   Conventional
Dallas/Ft. Worth    2019/1/20   Conventional
Denver  2019/1/20   Conventional
Detroit 2019/1/20   Conventional
Grand Rapids    2019/1/20   Conventional
Great Lakes 2019/1/20   Conventional
Harrisburg/Scranton 2019/1/20   Conventional
Hartford/Springfield    2019/1/20   Conventional
Houston 2019/1/20   Conventional
Indianapolis    2019/1/20   Conventional
Jacksonville    2019/1/20   Conventional
Las Vegas   2019/1/20   Conventional
Los Angeles 2019/1/20   Conventional
Louisville  2019/1/20   Conventional
Miami/Ft. Lauderdale    2019/1/20   Conventional
Midsouth    2019/1/20   Conventional
Nashville   2019/1/20   Conventional
New Orleans/Mobile  2019/1/20   Conventional
New York    2019/1/20   Conventional
Northeast   2019/1/20   Conventional
Northern New England    2019/1/20   Conventional
Orlando 2019/1/20   Conventional
Philadelphia    2019/1/20   Conventional
Phoenix/Tucson  2019/1/20   Conventional
Pittsburgh  2019/1/20   Conventional
Plains  2019/1/20   Conventional
Portland    2019/1/20   Conventional
Raleigh/Greensboro  2019/1/20   Conventional
Richmond/Norfolk    2019/1/20   Conventional
Roanoke 2019/1/20   Conventional
Sacramento  2019/1/20   Conventional
San Diego   2019/1/20   Conventional
San Francisco   2019/1/20   Conventional
Seattle 2019/1/20   Conventional
South Carolina  2019/1/20   Conventional
South Central   2019/1/20   Conventional
Southeast   2019/1/20   Conventional
Spokane 2019/1/20   Conventional
St. Louis   2019/1/20   Conventional
Syracuse    2019/1/20   Conventional
Tampa   2019/1/20   Conventional
West    2019/1/20   Conventional
West Tex/New Mexico 2019/1/20   Conventional
Albany  2019/1/20   Organic
Atlanta 2019/1/20   Organic
Baltimore/Washington    2019/1/20   Organic
Boise   2019/1/20   Organic
Boston  2019/1/20   Organic
Buffalo/Rochester   2019/1/20   Organic
California  2019/1/20   Organic
Charlotte   2019/1/20   Organic
Chicago 2019/1/20   Organic
Cincinnati/Dayton   2019/1/20   Organic
Columbus    2019/1/20   Organic
Dallas/Ft. Worth    2019/1/20   Organic
Denver  2019/1/20   Organic
Detroit 2019/1/20   Organic
Grand Rapids    2019/1/20   Organic
Great Lakes 2019/1/20   Organic
Harrisburg/Scranton 2019/1/20   Organic
Hartford/Springfield    2019/1/20   Organic
Houston 2019/1/20   Organic
Indianapolis    2019/1/20   Organic
Jacksonville    2019/1/20   Organic
Las Vegas   2019/1/20   Organic
Los Angeles 2019/1/20   Organic
Louisville  2019/1/20   Organic
Miami/Ft. Lauderdale    2019/1/20   Organic
Midsouth    2019/1/20   Organic
Nashville   2019/1/20   Organic
New Orleans/Mobile  2019/1/20   Organic
New York    2019/1/20   Organic
Northeast   2019/1/20   Organic
Northern New England    2019/1/20   Organic
Orlando 2019/1/20   Organic
Philadelphia    2019/1/20   Organic
Phoenix/Tucson  2019/1/20   Organic
Pittsburgh  2019/1/20   Organic
Plains  2019/1/20   Organic
Portland    2019/1/20   Organic
Raleigh/Greensboro  2019/1/20   Organic
Richmond/Norfolk    2019/1/20   Organic
Roanoke 2019/1/20   Organic
Sacramento  2019/1/20   Organic
San Diego   2019/1/20   Organic
San Francisco   2019/1/20   Organic
Seattle 2019/1/20   Organic
South Carolina  2019/1/20   Organic
South Central   2019/1/20   Organic
Southeast   2019/1/20   Organic
Spokane 2019/1/20   Organic
St. Louis   2019/1/20   Organic
Syracuse    2019/1/20   Organic
Tampa   2019/1/20   Organic
West    2019/1/20   Organic
West Tex/New Mexico 2019/1/20   Organic
```

Comment: Can you explain what your ultimate goal is?  `avocadodata$Region <- factor(avocadodata$Region)`, without specifying `levels` as a subset of the actual values, will produce a factor with no `<NA>`s.  Why do you need to specify `levels` the way you did, and why do you need a separate factor that avoids `<NA>`s?

Comment: @A.S.K., my goal is to set all the cities to one factor (e.g. "All cities") along with regions to categorize the whole column into 9 factors. Then generate a ggplot2 histogram with ```Region``` column sepreated by other columns (e.g. sales)

Comment: Hmm, I'm still having trouble picturing the final product.  Could you post a sketch of what you'd like the graph to look like?